# How to deal with possibility of viruses on Dropbox, Google Drive, external hard drive, etc?

Tags: malware, virus, antivirus, flash, pdf

For home use, what is the best way to deal with viruses that could be on external storage, which seems like a great way for hackers to persist on your system even after a reformat. Maybe the best practice is to just not store file types that are often hacked like PDF, flash, etc? Or is Dropbox and Google Drive good enough at detecting malicious files?

Comment: Force your ISP to use a CASB (Cloud Access Security Broker)

Comment: If you're worried about unauthorised modification, hash your files and store the hash in a different place you trust (if it's just one file you are concerned about you could even just print the hash out and stick it next to your desk). Then before you open you can validate the hash... it will change on modification of course so not great if you need to modify a lot.

Comment: @Matthew1471 Which tools/languages would you use to automate that for thousands of files worth many gigabytes?

Comment: @Sandeep Could we really force residential Comcast to use a CASB?

Comment: Look up the md5sum or sha1 sum Linux command line. It can get the hash values of loads of files recursively and output them to a text file. You could then use grep to find the hash value of the filename in the text file and update it everytime you make a change. Or perhaps write a small bash shell script to get the hash values then compare them automatically every x day or something. But it might take a while to do that every day or slow your machine down. It's been a while since I did  that so can't remember the exact commands but it's simple enough if I remember correctly

Comment: @Spectre Thanks for the tips; good stuff to know about the md5sum and sha1 commands. I guess this process could work as long as you don't get rooted at any point by opening one of these malicious files, which would allow the hacker to sabotage this process? Also, maybe some vulnerabilities in the OS (which might generate a preview of a PDF, images, videos, etc) could get you rooted without even manually opening the file? It seems a lot of effort and painstaking diligence for individuals to deal with these kinds of things.

Comment: @CarlGammaSagan I personally use http://code.kliu.org/hashcheck/ but MD5Summer was also pretty good (though I would override defaults and use the SHA1 option not MD5). It depends how regular you need to modify the files, if it's things like employment contracts hashing and e-mailing to yourself is viable. If it's EVERYTHING on your PC then this isn't going to work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this your own home machine? If it's a work network I would just block Google drive, Dropbox etc. People tend to take things home and work on them but means you have no control over the company data.

With that said I looked around a bit and it really depends on the provider some scan some don't and leave it to you to have a scanner installed. So I would just do some research on a provider before you use their services, at least that way you'll know where you stand.

I found the following in the security section about [Google Drive](https://support.google.com/a/answer/172541?hl=en).

> Virus scanning: Google Drive scans a file for viruses before the file
>   is downloaded or shared. If a virus is detected, users can't share the
>   file with others, send the infected file via email, or convert it to a
>   Google Doc, Sheet, or Slide, and they'll receive a warning if they
>   attempt these operations. The owner can download the virus-infected
>   file, but only after acknowledging the risk of doing so.
>
> Only files smaller than 25 MB can be scanned for viruses. For larger
>   files, a warning is displayed saying that the file can't be scanned.

I didn't find much on Dropbox except the [Dropbox help](https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/8406) page.

> Dropbox will sync any files added to it, so if someone syncs a virus or malware file, it will be synced to any computers linked to the account. Other users' accounts and computers may also be affected if the virus or malware is in a shared folder. Malware files are generally not activated unless you click on them to open them. For this reason, just as with files from any other source, we recommend that you follow good security practices, such as running anti-virus software and exercising due caution when running unknown files from other computers.

I also found another question related to this [Does Dropbox offer any protection against infected files?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/83667/does-dropbox-offer-any-protection-against-infected-files)

Comment: Yes, it is home use. It seems like such a big hassle to deal with potential viruses that could be lurking in Dropbox, Google Drive, and external hard drives. Targeted attacks could easily bypass AV blacklisting. Even widespread viruses could easily persist on our systems because Dropbox and external hard drives have no AV.

Comment: You can tell your AV to scan external drives and your dropbox folder. Its the nature of AV they detect known viruses, trojans and other malware (signiture based). they cant detect unkwown, there's a alot of research going into anomaly based detection but not sure if it would come to home users yet. What av do you use?

Comment: Yea, that's true. But many previous news stories about many AV companies and Google's Project Zero do not inspire a lot of confidence in AV companies in general. I'm using Avast for Windows and not using AV on my Mac or Linux/Unix now but maybe I should start? Have any recommendations?

Comment: Yeah you should have AV on all your machines, i never understand why people say you don't. for Linux ClamAV Antivirus is the most used i think. For Mac i cant say, i don't really use Macs that much. It does suck and they do get a lot of flack for being slow but there isn't  much they can do other than research or just politely ask hackers what malware they have made recently. And yeah you can just tell Avast to scan and watch your external hard drive.

Comment: The AV companies do have a pretty hard job relying primarily on blacklisting . I've heard that whitelisting like in the mobile app stores is a much better model, already adopted in Mac OS (though the user can override it, just like Android sideloading). Perhaps whitelisting will be the trend in the future if consumers really push for it. Especially against targeted attacks (which can likely happen to the personal electronics of engineers at big companies), whitelisting seems so much better.

Comment: @CarlGammaSagan : Media love to shout about EVERYTHING that they don't understand. In the buzzfeed era, this is even worst.  Whitelisting at the user endpoint is a naive thinking, it affect link data usability so much that it never pickup the pace in consumer zone. The media smearing on antivirus industry is as bad as the anti-vaccine movement, which is great news for malware toolkit creator.

Comment: @CarlGammaSagan just came across this and thought you might be intrested in how malware gets around AV etc... https://breakdev.org/defeating-antivirus-real-time-protection-from-the-inside/